# Share Extension not showing up from apps other than system apps

Tags: ios, swift, ios11, ios-extensions, share-extension

I am creating new share extension for my iOS 11 supported app. My share extension is working 100% fine for 'Photos' app as well as 'Files' app. But when i am testing the same app for all other apps apart from System apps. It is not showing my share extension from those apps like - 'Drive' app or 'Dropbox' app.

Is share extension in debug mode doesn't work with 3rd party apps? or is there any setting/configuration i need to add in my app to support other 3rd party apps to use my share extension. Any suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

Simple answer:

log messages are not printed, however you can stop at breakpoints, and then print everything using lldb.

1 Run your app

2 While the app is running, go to Debug -> Attach to process by PID or name

[image]

[image]

4 Then run your extension in any way you can do this on your device.

5 Wait for the debugger to stop the extension at the breakpoint.